# Best practice ajax loading more images(content) randomly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have 1000 images in a database. On page load I am randomly showing 60 images, when user scrolls I add 20 images through an AJAX request.

**First method** which I did was load all images into a container and then hide all and show 60 first images and on scroll start showing every 20 more. But the problem is that page loads all display none images as well (all 1k images).

**Second method** Load randomly 60 images from DB. Then on scroll Load extra 20 images:

```
var id_array=[];
$('.items').each(function(index, element) {
    id_array.push($(this).data('id'));
});

$.post("request.php", {
    send:  "true",
    json:JSON.stringify(id_array),
    }, function(response) {
        add_content(response);
    });
```

I am running through all images to get their id, then am sending json to php to do an SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (json, ids, right,here) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 20
```

The problem is if there are 1000 images on screen and adding more, then

```
WHERE id NOT IN (1000, items)
```

will be very slow, right?

How I could improve this performance as it sometimes laggy and obviously not optimized?

Comment: Why not load the page with all 1000 image paths in javascript. Then coordinate random selections 100% client-side.

Comment: yea I had same idea, just question if on mobile javascript array gonna work properly with those paths and on random it won't struggle

Comment: Each "path" could be a short segment of the entire URL - just the part that varies. If that part was an integer, then the whole client-side storage/randomization issue will be minimized and the coding would be reasonably simple.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a best practice, but I thought about just fetching the image paths into an array, using `shuffle()` on it and storing it in a session variable.
You could then use `array_slice()` to return parts of it for each subsequent request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing 20 images on page loads then pull first 20 records on page load. And then display it on you page. After that when user scroll down and reached bottom of the page, you can again do a ajax call for next 20 records and so on. And when user reached a point when there is no more records present do not call ajax any more.

This way you can optimize your codes and pulling 20 records will be faster then pulling 60 records.

Hope this idea will helps you to make your page loads faster in a better way.

Comment: That is **NOT** random, which defies the question entirely

Comment: OK, it's random then just pull random 20 records. Updated my ans. Thnx

Comment: The answer should involve getting random rows and optimising its performance when retrieving other rows using AJAX.